# saving data to mysql db using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making a register page for user. There I created the mysql db, webpage called signup and necessary laravel files including controller and web.php. but the problem is when I sent the data by filling the form in signup page, only the 'email'and 'password' field get stored in the mysql db. others are filled with default 'NULL'. Here I inserted all the pictures of files which will be usefull to check the problem.

[signup.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRrGw.png)
[Pagecontroller.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM7V7.png)
[web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRbTi.png)
[signup form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx2nd.png)`signup form filled with information`
[problematic db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcztP.png)`only email and password filled with data others are NULL`
[User.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h3gY.png)`user model`
[mysql db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAbmJ.png)

Comment: You are using base auth? Also show please your User model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your attributes to `fillable()` array in your `User` model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'username', 'first_name','last_name','phone_number','address','password'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

At `App\User.php` add:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'address',
    'email',
    'phone_number',
    'username',
    'password'
];
```

And also will be good if you will add at user observer at `creating` and `updating` method something like this:

```
if ($user->isDirty('password'))
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($user->password);
}
```

Of course include `use Hash` at top of observer

Read about observers: [LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers)